# Text aligning in CSS not moving text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get all the non bolded letters to float right and all be aligned vertically but i am unable to do so, with just using the float right the UL stays to the far left side. Another thing that i am unable to figure out is how would i be able to get the none bold things to align vertically. when I did vertical align nothing would happen to the first two sections.

```css
body{
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

#header{
  background-color: rgb(80, 177, 241);
  background-size: 200px 300px;
}
#img{
  height: 10px;
  width: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#header h1, p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0; 
  margin-bottom: 0px;
} 
#Container{

  margin: auto;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
#objective b{
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#objective {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#skills b{
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#skills {
  margin-left: 50px;

}
#experience b{
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#experience {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
#edu b{
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#edu {
  padding-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#footer{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Moses Saygbe Resume</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="Container">

      <div id="resume">

        <div id="header">
          <div id="img">
          <img src="Mosespic.jpg" alt="mp" style="widows: 100px;height: 125px;">
          </div>
          <h1>Moses Saygbe</h1>
          <p>800 s Main Street, StPaul, MN, 55109
            <br>
            Phone:763-273-6836
            <br>
            Email:saygbem@csp.com, WWW: http://www.mosessaygbe.com
          </p>
        </div>

        <!--This is where the list for the resume content goes.-->
        <div id="info">
          <p id="objective">
          <b>Objective</b>
          To graduate with my bachelors in Computer science and get a job right out of college.
          </p>
          <p id="skills"> 
          <b>Skills & Abilities</b>
          I know Python C++, and am learning HTML.
          <p id="experience">
          <b>Experience</b>
            <i>Connexus Energy</i>
            <br>
            <i>Jan 2019 – Sep 2019</i>
            <br>
            <ul>
              <li>Ensure quality technical support services are provided to employees in a timely manner</li>
              <li>Integrate PCs into the office environment, including the assembly, configuration, maintenance and follow- up</li>
              <li>Install and configure software and hardware for PCs and laptops</li>
              <li>Maintain copiers, printers, and fax machines</li>
              <li>Perform daily technical support health checks by</li> visually monitoring and reporting health status indicators to technical staff</li>
              <li>Cover the IT support phone line and provide first level support</li>
              <li>Process, record and prioritize all IT support requests as directed</li>
              <li>Monitor pool laptop activity and reconcile pool inventory to checked-out devices</li> 
            </ul>
            <i>Capital One</i>
            <br>
            <i>Oct 2018 – May 2019</i>
            <br>
            <ul>
              <li>Mentored/Trained New employees</li>
              <li>Led team-based meetings/training, Teaching new sales and technical techniques</li>
              <li>Servicied customer Bank accounts</li>
              <li>Provided App troubleshooting with customers servicing their accounts over the phone or online</li>
              <li>Provided personal financial counseling and build relationships with existing and new customers.</li> 
            </ul>
            <i>Best Buy</i>
            <br>
            <i>Aug 2013 – Mar 2018</i>
            <br>
            <ul>
              <li>Supported sales strategies in partnership with the Sales Manager to achieve operating results, growth objectives, and overall financial performance goals</li>
              <li>Ensured inventory and merchandising standards are maintained in-store area</li>
              <li>Trained New-hires on sale techniques and day to day Responsibilities</li>
              <li>Handled large amounts of money, and expensive merchandise</li>
            </ul>
            </p>
          <p id="edu">
          <b>Education</b>
            <i>Elk River High School</i>
            <br>
            <i>Class of 2012</i>
            <br>
            General studies
          <br>
          <br>
            <i>Concordia University, St. Paul</i>
            <br>
            <i>Class of 2021</i>
            <br>
            Bachelors of science
            </p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="footer">
          Moses Saygbe, Phone: 763-273-6836, Email:saygbem@csp.com
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As best as I could tell, you were trying to get all of the bold headings on the left to align, all of the content on the right to align, and then have them aligned vertically as well. Which ends up being a table. Due to the initial overuse of `<table>` for layout, it's gotten a pretty bad reputation, but when the thing you're trying to lay out is a table, it's perfect for the job:

```css
body{
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

#header{
  background-color: rgb(80, 177, 241);
  background-size: 200px 300px;
}
#img{
  height: 10px;
  width: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#header h1, p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0; 
  margin-bottom: 0px;
} 
#Container{

  margin: auto;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
table {
  margin-left: 50px; /* points or em would be cleaner */
}
th, td {
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-width: 8em; /* tweak for left column sizing */
}
#footer{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Moses Saygbe Resume</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="Container">

      <div id="resume">

        <div id="header">
          <div id="img">
          <img src="Mosespic.jpg" alt="mp" style="widows: 100px;height: 125px;">
          </div>
          <h1>Moses Saygbe</h1>
          <p>800 s Main Street, StPaul, MN, 55109
            <br>
            Phone:763-273-6836
            <br>
            Email:saygbem@csp.com, WWW: http://www.mosessaygbe.com
          </p>
        </div>

        <!--This is where the list for the resume content goes.-->
        <div id="info">
          <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Objective</th>
              <td>To graduate with my bachelors in Computer science and get a job right out of college.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Skills & Abilities</th>
              <td>I know Python C++, and am learning HTML.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Experience</th>
              <td>
            <i>Connexus Energy</i>
            <br>
            <i>Jan 2019 – Sep 2019</i>
            <br>
            <ul>
              <li>Ensure quality technical support services are provided to employees in a timely manner</li>
              <li>Integrate PCs into the office environment, including the assembly, configuration, maintenance and follow- up</li>
              <li>Install and configure software and hardware for PCs and laptops</li>
              <li>Maintain copiers, printers, and fax machines</li>
              <li>Perform daily technical support health checks by</li> visually monitoring and reporting health status indicators to technical staff</li>
              <li>Cover the IT support phone line and provide first level support</li>
              <li>Process, record and prioritize all IT support requests as directed</li>
              <li>Monitor pool laptop activity and reconcile pool inventory to checked-out devices</li> 
            </ul>
            <i>Capital One</i>
            <br>
            <i>Oct 2018 – May 2019</i>
            <br>
            <ul>
              <li>Mentored/Trained New employees</li>
              <li>Led team-based meetings/training, Teaching new sales and technical techniques</li>
              <li>Servicied customer Bank accounts</li>
              <li>Provided App troubleshooting with customers servicing their accounts over the phone or online</li>
              <li>Provided personal financial counseling and build relationships with existing and new customers.</li> 
            </ul>
            <i>Best Buy</i>
            <br>
            <i>Aug 2013 – Mar 2018</i>
            <br>
            <ul>
              <li>Supported sales strategies in partnership with the Sales Manager to achieve operating results, growth objectives, and overall financial performance goals</li>
              <li>Ensured inventory and merchandising standards are maintained in-store area</li>
              <li>Trained New-hires on sale techniques and day to day Responsibilities</li>
              <li>Handled large amounts of money, and expensive merchandise</li>
            </ul>
          </dd>
          <dt>Education</dt>
          <dd>
            <i>Elk River High School</i>
            <br>
            <i>Class of 2012</i>
            <br>
            General studies
          <br>
          <br>
            <i>Concordia University, St. Paul</i>
            <br>
            <i>Class of 2021</i>
            <br>
            Bachelors of science
          </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div id="footer">
          Moses Saygbe, Phone: 763-273-6836, Email:saygbem@csp.com
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```